# Turning a web page into a mobile app

Tags: php, android, html, ios, iphone

This question may have already been answered.  But I want to make sure I get the best answer for what I am trying to do.

I want to design a site on my website to look and function like an app. I will use a combination of HTML, CSS, JavaScript/jquery, PHP, and will use MySQL databases.

I want to then turn this into an app.  I would prefer to be able for the app to just pull content from the page if possible.  Basically the webpage loads inside the app.  This will allow me to "update" without having to submit an app update to the app store.

I want this to be available on all app stores (iOS, Google play store, Windows, etc) for phones and tablets.

I would also like to be able to utilize push notifications as well.

I've never done this before so hopefully, this will be easy to learn.

Any suggestions or tips? The more details you can provide the better.  Sorry if this is a bad question or in wrong place. just hoping to get some positive feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want your app to be native for all mobile platforms, you have to code separately in all platforms. You can check individual developer sites for iOS, Android and Windows to get started.
2. From your question, it looks like you have idea of web design and development and want to make mobile apps. Write code once and build for every platform.
   You can use some of your previous knowledge and can learn to make a hybrid app. 
   You can have a look at these options -  http://phonegap.com/, https://ionicframework.com/, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/

Comment: I've looked into phone gap.  I guess my question comes in at...

1) Can I set up an app inside phone gap to where it loads a site?

2) When I do this, does it literally just pull content from the site once or can i edit the site and the new content will automatically be available to people with the app when they refresh or reopen the app?

Comment: As the question was tagged with php, android, html, ios, iphone, we being native developers suggested some ways to solve your problem. Now it has become a phonegap particular problem, you can have a tag for phonegap in your question so that phonegap developers can answer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can using webview to load your web and build to ios app.

Comment: I guess my question comes in at...When I do this, does it literally just pull content from the site once or can i edit the site and the new content will automatically be available to people with the app when they refresh or reopen the app without them having to update the app?

Comment: yes sure . because your app is your transform website.